# Cannot find compilation library location for package 'System.Drawing.Common' in Nopcommerce 4.3 while running from iis

Tags: .net-core, model-view-controller, nopcommerce

I'm trying to run my **Nopcommerce 4.3 store from  IIS** rather than  running **from  Visual  studio**.

But is is always showing me

> Cannot find compilation library location for package
> 'System.Drawing.Common'

when i run  from  visual  studio, it runs successfully without any error.
Kindly take me in the right direction  to resolve it. Do i need to add any package reference?

[image]

Comment: you might need to install some IIS packages like "URL Rewrite 2.1" via the web platform installer